# Pip install returning a ValueError

Tags: python, pip, ssl-certificate, valueerror

I recently tried to install a library using Pip, and I received this error message. I am unable to install any packages, as the same error message keeps popping up.

I notice this problem in both my main enviroment, and my venv Virtual Environment.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -illow (c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -aleido (c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -illow (c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -aleido (c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)

  ...

    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 57, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 401, in connect
    context.verify_mode = resolve_cert_reqs(self.cert_reqs)
  File "c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\ssl.py", line 720, in verify_mode
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).verify_mode.__set__(self, value)
ValueError: Cannot set verify_mode to CERT_NONE when check_hostname is enabled.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -illow (c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -aleido (c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -illow (c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -aleido (c:\users\brdwoo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by hard-coding in a 1, instead of having CERT_NONE being passed to verify_mode.

The error message gave me the location of the code:

```
 File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 738, in verify_mode
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).verify_mode.__set__(self, 0)
ValueError: Cannot set verify_mode to CERT_NONE when check_hostname is enabled.
```

I swapped the variable ***value*** -> ***1***

```
@verify_mode.setter
def verify_mode(self, value):
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).verify_mode.__set__(self, 1)
```

Comment: Please canb bring more explanation on how you handled it @drew because I dont understand what you have done .

Answer (score 8):

This occurs due to files names with the '~' prefix in site-packages. Please remove those files / folders. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Just warnings. Have nothing with SSL checking host names.

Comment: This is the solution to remove the warnings. It is not the solution to the ERROR of the question. However, it's worth mentioning I think.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have pip-system-certs installed? Try uninstalling it, and see if your problem goes away. It did for me (but I am unsure of the consequences in a python 3.10 environment)

Answer (score 0):

[WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (~lib\site-packages)e][1]

Hello, I had a similar problem where Visual Studio Code couldn't find installed libraries. The problem occurred after updating the Python version. What I did is shown in the steps 1 and 2 in the picture - I selected the Python version from the dropdown in the upper right corner, and in step 2, I switched to an older, working version. I hope this helps someone...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDjr4.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If anyone happens to be using a Google Colab notebook like me, I was able to resolve this issue by Selecting "runtime" at the top, and then fully disconnecting and restarting the code in a new runtime.